# Excel Copying cell value depending on the value of another cell

Tags: excel, copy

I have two sheet in excel, Sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Sheet 1 column A has some data written lets say A1 its Check1, A2 its Check2 and so on so forth. Column B where has either Pass or Fail.

What i have to do is if there is a Fail in lets say cell B1 and cell B4, the corresponding value in cell A1 and cell A4 should be copied in Sheet 2 but in A1 and A2 cells of sheet 2. is it possible?

I have tried to explain it below as well, if the above is not clear

Sheet 1 A B ......

1 Check1 Fail

2 Check2 Pass

3 Check3 Pass

4 Check4 Fail . . .

Sheet 2  A B .....

1 Check1

2 Check4

3

4
. . .

I hope this clarifies, If any value in b column of sheet 1 is "fail" the value of corresponding A cell should be copied in sheet 2

Thanks

Comment: What did you try yourself to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very possible, but it will require some strange formulas and the use of Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula. Below is the exact formula for the case you gave.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4="Fail",ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4)),ROW()),1),"")
```

Here is a small break down of the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([values you want to return],SMALL(IF([Criteria Array]=[Criteria],ROW([Array you are looking up])),ROW()),1),"")
```

Paste this in cell A1 in sheet2, and click like you are going to edit the formula, but them press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. This will add {} brackets around the formula and make it an array formula. Then you can click the bottom right corner and drag it down column A in sheet2. It will populate A1 and A2 with Check1 and Check4.

Comment: Thanks. works like a charm. you are a life saver :). I am being greedy now. What if I have multiple sheets like Sheet 1 and from all sheets i want the corresponding value to "Fail" to copied in sheet 2. very much appreciating your help. thanks

Comment: That's where I think a VBA macro would be the best way. If you find yourself doing the same thing over and over again, then a macro usually is the best solution. Do you know any VBA?

Comment: Hello Blake, I am sorry if i sound too naive because i am very new to excel. i tested this formula and was working very well when values in my sheet start from A1 and B1. but if i use it on a sheet where data on my sheet is like all checks are in B  Column starting from B9 cell and Fail is in C column starting from C9 cell, it doesnt work. I tried to play around the formula but it is not working. can you help please.